# Android.mk *** missing separator. Stop. The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android.mk

I cloned the following Telegram repo from Github:
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
I am using a PC not Apple.

I opened the project in Android Studio. I then linked the project with the C++ files, which are included in the repo. I did this with ndkBuild and the Android.mk which is also included in the repo.

When I try to build it in Android Studio using  gradle, I get the following error messages:

In prebuilt-library.mk:

```
Error:(27, 0) *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

In Android.mk:

```
Android NDK: ERROR:C:\Users\...\workspace\project_name\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:avutil: The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item
```

This is the Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avutil

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv7-a/libavutil.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv5te/libavutil.a
    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/i686/libavutil.a
        endif
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avformat

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv7-a/libavformat.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv5te/libavformat.a
    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/i686/libavformat.a
        endif
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avcodec

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv7-a/libavcodec.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv5te/libavcodec.a
    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/i686/libavcodec.a
        endif
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := crypto

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./boringssl/lib/libcrypto_armeabi-v7a.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./boringssl/lib/libcrypto_armeabi.a
    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
        LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./boringssl/lib/libcrypto_x86.a
        endif
    endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := breakpad
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wall -std=c++11 -DANDROID -finline-functions -ffast-math -Os -fno-strict-aliasing

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
./breakpad/common/android/include \
./breakpad

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./breakpad/client/linux/crash_generation/crash_generation_client.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/dump_writer_common/ucontext_reader.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/dump_writer_common/thread_info.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/log/log.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/microdump_writer/microdump_writer.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_ptrace_dumper.cc \
./breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.cc \
./breakpad/client/minidump_file_writer.cc \
./breakpad/common/android/breakpad_getcontext.S \
./breakpad/common/convert_UTF.c \
./breakpad/common/md5.cc \
./breakpad/common/string_conversion.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/elfutils.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/file_id.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/guid_creator.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/linux_libc_support.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/memory_mapped_file.cc \
./breakpad/common/linux/safe_readlink.cc

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -Wall -std=c++11 -DANDROID -frtti -DHAVE_PTHREAD -finline-functions -ffast-math -Os
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./boringssl/include/
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := tgnet
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := crypto

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./tgnet/BuffersStorage.cpp \
./tgnet/ByteArray.cpp \
./tgnet/ByteStream.cpp \
./tgnet/Connection.cpp \
./tgnet/ConnectionSession.cpp \
./tgnet/ConnectionsManager.cpp \
./tgnet/ConnectionSocket.cpp \
./tgnet/Datacenter.cpp \
./tgnet/EventObject.cpp \
./tgnet/FileLog.cpp \
./tgnet/MTProtoScheme.cpp \
./tgnet/NativeByteBuffer.cpp \
./tgnet/Request.cpp \
./tgnet/Timer.cpp \
./tgnet/TLObject.cpp \
./tgnet/Config.cpp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -DANDROID -DHAVE_MALLOC_H -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DWEBP_USE_THREAD -finline-functions -ffast-math -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ./libwebp/src
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
LOCAL_MODULE := webp

ifneq ($(findstring armeabi-v7a, $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)),)
  NEON := c.neon
else
  NEON := c
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./libwebp/dec/alpha.c \
./libwebp/dec/buffer.c \
./libwebp/dec/frame.c \
./libwebp/dec/idec.c \
./libwebp/dec/io.c \
./libwebp/dec/quant.c \
./libwebp/dec/tree.c \
./libwebp/dec/vp8.c \
./libwebp/dec/vp8l.c \
./libwebp/dec/webp.c \
./libwebp/dsp/alpha_processing.c \
./libwebp/dsp/alpha_processing_sse2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/cpu.c \
./libwebp/dsp/dec.c \
./libwebp/dsp/dec_clip_tables.c \
./libwebp/dsp/dec_mips32.c \
./libwebp/dsp/dec_neon.$(NEON) \
./libwebp/dsp/dec_sse2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/enc.c \
./libwebp/dsp/enc_avx2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/enc_mips32.c \
./libwebp/dsp/enc_neon.$(NEON) \
./libwebp/dsp/enc_sse2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/lossless.c \
./libwebp/dsp/lossless_mips32.c \
./libwebp/dsp/lossless_neon.$(NEON) \
./libwebp/dsp/lossless_sse2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/upsampling.c \
./libwebp/dsp/upsampling_neon.$(NEON) \
./libwebp/dsp/upsampling_sse2.c \
./libwebp/dsp/yuv.c \
./libwebp/dsp/yuv_mips32.c \
./libwebp/dsp/yuv_sse2.c \
./libwebp/enc/alpha.c \
./libwebp/enc/analysis.c \
./libwebp/enc/backward_references.c \
./libwebp/enc/config.c \
./libwebp/enc/cost.c \
./libwebp/enc/filter.c \
./libwebp/enc/frame.c \
./libwebp/enc/histogram.c \
./libwebp/enc/iterator.c \
./libwebp/enc/picture.c \
./libwebp/enc/picture_csp.c \
./libwebp/enc/picture_psnr.c \
./libwebp/enc/picture_rescale.c \
./libwebp/enc/picture_tools.c \
./libwebp/enc/quant.c \
./libwebp/enc/syntax.c \
./libwebp/enc/token.c \
./libwebp/enc/tree.c \
./libwebp/enc/vp8l.c \
./libwebp/enc/webpenc.c \
./libwebp/utils/bit_reader.c \
./libwebp/utils/bit_writer.c \
./libwebp/utils/color_cache.c \
./libwebp/utils/filters.c \
./libwebp/utils/huffman.c \
./libwebp/utils/huffman_encode.c \
./libwebp/utils/quant_levels.c \
./libwebp/utils/quant_levels_dec.c \
./libwebp/utils/random.c \
./libwebp/utils/rescaler.c \
./libwebp/utils/thread.c \
./libwebp/utils/utils.c \

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := thumb
else
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
endif
LOCAL_MODULE := sqlite
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -DHAVE_STRCHRNUL=0

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
./sqlite/sqlite3.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

LOCAL_MODULE    := tmessages.22
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -DBSD=1 -ffast-math -Os -funroll-loops -std=c++11
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -ljnigraphics -llog -lz -latomic
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := webp sqlite tgnet breakpad avformat avcodec avutil

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
./opus/src/opus.c \
./opus/src/opus_decoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_encoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream_encoder.c \
./opus/src/opus_multistream_decoder.c \
./opus/src/repacketizer.c \
./opus/src/analysis.c \
./opus/src/mlp.c \
./opus/src/mlp_data.c

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DLIBYUV_NEON
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLIBYUV_NEON
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm

    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
        LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Dx86fix
        LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Dx86fix
        LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
        LOCAL_SRC_FILE += \
        ./libyuv/source/row_x86.asm
        endif
    endif
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/silk/CNG.c \
./opus/silk/code_signs.c \
./opus/silk/init_decoder.c \
./opus/silk/decode_core.c \
./opus/silk/decode_frame.c \
./opus/silk/decode_parameters.c \
./opus/silk/decode_indices.c \
./opus/silk/decode_pulses.c \
./opus/silk/decoder_set_fs.c \
./opus/silk/dec_API.c \
./opus/silk/enc_API.c \
./opus/silk/encode_indices.c \
./opus/silk/encode_pulses.c \
./opus/silk/gain_quant.c \
./opus/silk/interpolate.c \
./opus/silk/LP_variable_cutoff.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_decode.c \
./opus/silk/NSQ.c \
./opus/silk/NSQ_del_dec.c \
./opus/silk/PLC.c \
./opus/silk/shell_coder.c \
./opus/silk/tables_gain.c \
./opus/silk/tables_LTP.c \
./opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c \
./opus/silk/tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c \
./opus/silk/tables_other.c \
./opus/silk/tables_pitch_lag.c \
./opus/silk/tables_pulses_per_block.c \
./opus/silk/VAD.c \
./opus/silk/control_audio_bandwidth.c \
./opus/silk/quant_LTP_gains.c \
./opus/silk/VQ_WMat_EC.c \
./opus/silk/HP_variable_cutoff.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_encode.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_VQ.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_unpack.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_del_dec_quant.c \
./opus/silk/process_NLSFs.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_LR_to_MS.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_MS_to_LR.c \
./opus/silk/check_control_input.c \
./opus/silk/control_SNR.c \
./opus/silk/init_encoder.c \
./opus/silk/control_codec.c \
./opus/silk/A2NLSF.c \
./opus/silk/ana_filt_bank_1.c \
./opus/silk/biquad_alt.c \
./opus/silk/bwexpander_32.c \
./opus/silk/bwexpander.c \
./opus/silk/debug.c \
./opus/silk/decode_pitch.c \
./opus/silk/inner_prod_aligned.c \
./opus/silk/lin2log.c \
./opus/silk/log2lin.c \
./opus/silk/LPC_analysis_filter.c \
./opus/silk/LPC_inv_pred_gain.c \
./opus/silk/table_LSF_cos.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF2A.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_stabilize.c \
./opus/silk/NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c \
./opus/silk/pitch_est_tables.c \
./opus/silk/resampler.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_down2_3.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_down2.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_AR2.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_down_FIR.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_private_up2_HQ.c \
./opus/silk/resampler_rom.c \
./opus/silk/sigm_Q15.c \
./opus/silk/sort.c \
./opus/silk/sum_sqr_shift.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_decode_pred.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_encode_pred.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_find_predictor.c \
./opus/silk/stereo_quant_pred.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/silk/fixed/LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/corrMatrix_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/encode_frame_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_LPC_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_LTP_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_pitch_lags_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/find_pred_coefs_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/noise_shape_analysis_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/prefilter_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/process_gains_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/regularize_correlations_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy16_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/residual_energy_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/solve_LS_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/warped_autocorrelation_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/apply_sine_window_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/autocorr_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/burg_modified_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/k2a_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/k2a_Q16_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/vector_ops_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/schur64_FIX.c \
./opus/silk/fixed/schur_FIX.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/celt/bands.c \
./opus/celt/celt.c \
./opus/celt/celt_encoder.c \
./opus/celt/celt_decoder.c \
./opus/celt/cwrs.c \
./opus/celt/entcode.c \
./opus/celt/entdec.c \
./opus/celt/entenc.c \
./opus/celt/kiss_fft.c \
./opus/celt/laplace.c \
./opus/celt/mathops.c \
./opus/celt/mdct.c \
./opus/celt/modes.c \
./opus/celt/pitch.c \
./opus/celt/celt_lpc.c \
./opus/celt/quant_bands.c \
./opus/celt/rate.c \
./opus/celt/vq.c \
./opus/celt/arm/armcpu.c \
./opus/celt/arm/arm_celt_map.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./opus/ogg/bitwise.c \
./opus/ogg/framing.c \
./opus/opusfile/info.c \
./opus/opusfile/internal.c \
./opus/opusfile/opusfile.c \
./opus/opusfile/stream.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    := \
./opus/include \
./opus/silk \
./opus/silk/fixed \
./opus/celt \
./opus/ \
./opus/opusfile \
./libyuv/include \
./boringssl/include \
./breakpad/common/android/include \
./breakpad \
./ffmpeg/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./libjpeg/jcapimin.c \
./libjpeg/jcapistd.c \
./libjpeg/armv6_idct.S \
./libjpeg/jccoefct.c \
./libjpeg/jccolor.c \
./libjpeg/jcdctmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jchuff.c \
./libjpeg/jcinit.c \
./libjpeg/jcmainct.c \
./libjpeg/jcmarker.c \
./libjpeg/jcmaster.c \
./libjpeg/jcomapi.c \
./libjpeg/jcparam.c \
./libjpeg/jcphuff.c \
./libjpeg/jcprepct.c \
./libjpeg/jcsample.c \
./libjpeg/jctrans.c \
./libjpeg/jdapimin.c \
./libjpeg/jdapistd.c \
./libjpeg/jdatadst.c \
./libjpeg/jdatasrc.c \
./libjpeg/jdcoefct.c \
./libjpeg/jdcolor.c \
./libjpeg/jddctmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jdhuff.c \
./libjpeg/jdinput.c \
./libjpeg/jdmainct.c \
./libjpeg/jdmarker.c \
./libjpeg/jdmaster.c \
./libjpeg/jdmerge.c \
./libjpeg/jdphuff.c \
./libjpeg/jdpostct.c \
./libjpeg/jdsample.c \
./libjpeg/jdtrans.c \
./libjpeg/jerror.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctflt.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctfst.c \
./libjpeg/jfdctint.c \
./libjpeg/jidctflt.c \
./libjpeg/jidctfst.c \
./libjpeg/jidctint.c \
./libjpeg/jidctred.c \
./libjpeg/jmemmgr.c \
./libjpeg/jmemnobs.c \
./libjpeg/jquant1.c \
./libjpeg/jquant2.c \
./libjpeg/jutils.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./libyuv/source/compare_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_gcc.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/compare.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_from_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_from.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_jpeg.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_to_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert_to_i420.cc \
./libyuv/source/convert.cc \
./libyuv/source/cpu_id.cc \
./libyuv/source/mjpeg_decoder.cc \
./libyuv/source/mjpeg_validate.cc \
./libyuv/source/planar_functions.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_any.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_gcc.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/rotate.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_any.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_gcc.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/row_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_any.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_common.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_gcc.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_mips.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_neon64.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale_win.cc \
./libyuv/source/scale.cc \
./libyuv/source/video_common.cc

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLIBYUV_NEON
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
        ./libyuv/source/compare_neon.cc.neon    \
        ./libyuv/source/rotate_neon.cc.neon     \
        ./libyuv/source/row_neon.cc.neon        \
        ./libyuv/source/scale_neon.cc.neon
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     += \
./jni.c \
./audio.c \
./utils.c \
./image.c \
./video.c \
./gifvideo.cpp \
./SqliteWrapper.cpp \
./TgNetWrapper.cpp \
./NativeLoader.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

I thought that there might be problems with whitespaces, carriage returns and tabs. So I looked at the Android.mk in vi in my bash. This is a screenshot of the result:

[image: Android.mk in vi in bash]

I tried to remove tabs and added some, but I still can't make it work, so that the build is successful. 
Maybe the problem is something else?
Any Help is greatly appreciated as I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now.

Comment: can you add printout of LOCAL_SRC_FILES right before include prebuild? `$(warning $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))`

Answer (score 2):

'Missing separator' means make was expecting a tab or assignment character and didn't find once. Common causes are spaces instead of tabs (like you tried) or whitespace after a continuation-backslash character like in the the source list.

However, I suspect the real error message is the second one, and the missing separator thing is a side effect. It sounds like one of the `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` lines is seeing a source file list instead of a single compiled library in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. I don't see how that's happening though; the makefile includes `$(CLEAR_VARS)` after each, and LOCAL_SRC_FILES is redefined for each component. It's a little wierd how the find shared library target includes opus, libjpeg, and libyuv sources together.

Or perhaps none of the TARGET_ARCH_ABI ifeq branches match and PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY is being included with *nothing* in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. You can check this by adding an `else #error` and the end of an innermost ifeq.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the reply. Can you tell if there is anything wrong in the bash screenshot, e.g. tabs?

Comment: I didn't notice anything. All the lines in the the screenshot are include or assignment statements, which shouldn't care about the tabs-vs-spaces issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk#27

You have conditions that handle armeabi-v7a, armeabi, and x86, but nothing for arm64-v8a, x86_64, mips, or mips64. I'm guessing you haven't set `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86` in your Application.mk? The NDK is trying to build those other ABIs and finding zero source files for those.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply. I did set APP_ABI inside the application.mk. Do you have any other guesses why the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

set `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86` in the Application.mk seems not to work for the new gradle.

I am using gradle 2.2.1.

In the new version of Telegram, they add

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk", "APP_PLATFORM:=android-14"
            abiFilters   "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","x86"
        }
    }
```

to build.gradle. And write abi filters here works

Answer (score 0):

You have tabs (they're the `^I` symbols in your screenshot) in your makefile. Tabs have a very specific meaning in make and shouldn't be used for indentation. Replace the hard tabs with spaces and it should work.